# SwampDragon is not defined

Tags: django, swampdragon

Trying out tutorial [here](http://wildfish.com/blog/2014/12/09/swampdragon-real-time-django-notifications/)

settings.py

```
    DRAGON_URL = 'http://localhost:9999/'

    TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'notifications.context_processors.dragon_url',
)
```

SwampDragon settings

```
SWAMP_DRAGON_CONNECTION = ('swampdragon.connections.sockjs_connection.DjangoSubscriberConnection', '/data')
```

context_processors.py

```
from django.conf import settings

def dragon_url(request):
    return {'DRAGON_URL': settings.DRAGON_URL}
```

home.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load swampdragon_tags %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Notifications demo</h1>

<!-- This is our list of notifications -->
<ul id="notifications">
{% for notification in object_list %}
<li>{{ notification.message }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>


<!-- SwampDragon -->
{% swampdragon_settings %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'swampdragon/js/dist/swampdragon.js' %}"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'swampdragon/js/vendor/sockjs-0.3.4.min.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'swampdragon/js/legacy/swampdragon-vanilla.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'notifications.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'swampdragon/js/dist/datamapper.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ DRAGON_URL }}settings.js"></script>

<!-- notifications -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'notifications.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

error in console

```
ReferenceError: SwampDragon is not defined

var sdInstance = new SwampDragon(options);
```

Also tried to display settings in console

```
<script>
console.log(window.swampdragon_settings);
</script>
```

I get

```
endpoint        "/data"
```

Not sure what's wrong. Please let me know if more information is needed.

If needed pip freeze

```
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
certifi==2015.4.28
Django==1.7
django-filter==0.10.0
djangorestframework==3.1.3
Markdown==2.6.2
python-dateutil==2.4.2
redis==2.10.3
six==1.9.0
sockjs-tornado==1.0.1
SwampDragon==0.4.2.2
tornado==4.2
tornado-redis==2.4.18
wheel==0.24.0
```

Comment: I can't find the error. But I tried this tutorial 3 days ago and it works. So maybe you can try copy and paste everything and change code little by little to find where you error is.

Comment: @BoumTAC please have a look at the approach in my answer if it looks ok ? Though it works fine but I just wanted to confirm if this approach is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem was that tutorial I was following had some problems. Please see the question for link to tutorial.

I changed **notifications.js** to :

```
// Ask the browser for permission to show notifications
// Taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web   /API/Notification/Using_Web_Notifications
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (status) {
        // This allows to use Notification.permission with Chrome/Safari
        if (Notification.permission !== status) {
            Notification.permission = status;
        }
    });
});


// Create an instance of vanilla dragon
//var dragon = swampdragon.open({onopen: onOpen, onchannelmessage:    onChannelMessage});

// This is the list of notifications
var notificationsList = document.getElementById("notifications");

// New channel message received
swampdragon.onChannelMessage(function(channels, message){
// Add the notification
addNotification((message.data));
});

// SwampDragon connection open
swampdragon.open(function() {
// Once the connection is open, subscribe to notifications
swampdragon.subscribe('notifications', 'notifications');
});


// Add new notifications
function addNotification(notification) {
// If we have permission to show browser notifications
// we can show the notifiaction
if (window.Notification && Notification.permission === "granted") {
    new Notification(notification.message);
}

// Add the new notification
var li = document.createElement("li");
notificationsList.insertBefore(li, notificationsList.firstChild);
li.innerHTML = notification.message;

// Remove excess notifications
while (notificationsList.getElementsByTagName("li").length > 5) {
    notificationsList.getElementsByTagName("li")[5].remove();
}
}
```

Instead of using

```
var dragon = new VanillaDragon(...)
```

I instead used

```
swampdragon.<function name>
```

and it works.